# Validating AWS Access and Secret Keys

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, go

The regular expressions for AWS access key ids and secret keys [from the AWS security blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-safer-way-to-distribute-aws-credentials-to-ec2/) are:
AKID: `(?<![A-Z0-9])[A-Z0-9]{20}(?![A-Z0-9])`
SK:    `(?<![A-Za-z0-9/+=])[A-Za-z0-9/+=]{40}(?![A-Za-z0-9/+=])`

When I try to use these with the Go [regexp](https://godoc.org/regexp) package, it gives the following error for both expressions: `` error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?<` ``. I know that the Go regexp package does not fully support the Perl syntax, but I'm not sure how to represent the same expression so that it is supported by Go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason for validating the credentials separate from just using the credentials? Amazon does not guarantee that these regrexps will match all valid credentials in the future.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Secondly, why Go and why does this need lookarounds?

Comment: @FailSafe I have no idea why it uses lookarounds, they are just from the AWS security blog. I am using Go because the project is for school and that is the language that my group chose to use.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I am getting the credentials from the user and would like to do some sort of input validation

Comment: @AlexKrantz  Validate the credentials by using the credentials with the service.  If the credentials fail to match the regexp, then the credentials will also fail when used with the service.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I get that am able to just call the service, but I would like to be able to provide better user experience through a preliminary check.

Comment: @AlexKrantz What is the better user experience?  Is it that regexp fails faster than a preliminary check against the service, or are you not doing a preliminary check against the service?  I guess this is off topic from the regexp problem. I'll stop commenting.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I am not doing a preliminary check against the service and also that regexp fails faster.

Comment: Why are you even getting these credentials from the user? What use case are you aiming for?

Comment: @morras It is intended to be an automatic deployment script for a game and AWS is one of the platforms. So, I need the user's credentials to create the EC2 instance and configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above comments that the system takes users credentials and uses them to create EC2 isntances, this does not sound like the right place to use credentials. [IAM best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html) advices against sharing AIM credentials.

Depending on how the user is authenticated you should either use Cognito Identity pools to grant the permission to the user to create the instance when they use your service.

Or you can use STS to assume a role on behalf of the user.

Depending on how the service works it could also just have the IAM role needed to create the EC2 instances, and do user validation and logging in the service

Comment: Ok, now I realize I was going about this in the wrong way, thanks